# Why GUI different in Ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: ubuntu, gui

I have two machines, one is a brand new installation of Ubuntu 20.04, and the GUI looks like the first one.
Later on, I upgrade another machine from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.4, I see their GUI are different especially the file manager.

What are the two GUIs? aren't they GNOME?

and why upgrade to a different version of GUI?

[image: GUI 1]  [image: GUI 2]

Comment: The differences in appearance are most likely due to using a different or updated icon set, not primarily due to a different version of the GUI (which I assume means "desktop environment").  The "Why?" question is mostly uninteresting for you I suppose. I assume you're more interested in "How do I change the appearance so that it looks the same on both systems?", right?

Comment: Go into settings and checkout which theme and icons are in use. Adjust accordingly to set both to your preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install gnome-tweaks then I see the options for different icons.